# Получение вывода команды cron без редиректа

Tags: linux, bash

Что происходит если команда записанная в `crontab` выводит что-либо в `stdout` и/или `stderr`? Как сделать редирект и логировать вывод я понимаю, ответ типа

```
* * * * * /path/to/script 1>/path/to/stdout.log 2>/path/to/stderr.log
```

не нужен.

В целом нашел более-менее устраивающую меня ссылку: https://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal, но если кто-нибудь подскажет, как настроить e-mail оповещение, или более подробную информацию о работе `cron` (хотя бы, какое именно место курить в man), буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А у вас в начале /etc/crontab разве не указана переменная `MAILTO=почтовый@ящик`.  Вот на тот ящик он и шлет вывод. Только для корректной работы должен быть в системе установлен какой нибудь MTA, т.е. почтовый сервер. С простенькими MTA у меня обычно проблемы с отправкой бывают, а со старым добрым sendmail в стандартной конфигурации (ну разве что домен задать, relay снаружи от спамеров закрыть)  работает на ура.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 в `/etc/crontab` нет строчки `MAILTO=...`)) В каких еще файлах могут лежать настройки `cron`?

Comment: /var/spool/cron/*      Но могли по идее куда нибудь в conf.d или как он у вас называется вынести

Comment: @andy.37 Еще вопрос какой именно у вас крон. их много развелось в последнее время. я использую `vixie cron` от isc.org. Это вроде оригинальный крон, работавший в очень многих *nix системах. В принципе у меня даже в  man 5 crontab подробно описано про переменные в /etc/crontab

Comment: @andy.37 Посмотрел сейчас на дебиане, там в дефолтной конфигруции MAILTO не задан, но в man написано, что его можно добавить в crontab, наряду с PATH и прочими переменными

Comment: спасибо, пожалуй, приму Ваш ответ. В целом достаточно информации к размышлению))